# how to efficiently insert element for a n dimension array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, insert, concatenation

There is a simple example.

I have a 2d array

```
a=np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)+1

array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

and I wanna insert 0 (or any other value) in the beginning and end of the array, then it becomes

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I'm trying np.insert or np.concatenate, but I failed for >2 dimension. What is the fastest way to handle this kind of problem?

Comment: Fastest way would be initializing array of zeros and assigning. Did you try that?

Comment: That's the first way how I handle this problem, but if my matrix is huge, I'm not sure it's the fastest one, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.pad`:

```
>>> np.pad(a, 1, 'constant')
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: What if I only wanna pad one axis?

Comment: @kinderchan `np.pad(a, [(0, 0), (1, 1)], mode='constant')` or `np.pad(a, [(1, 1), (0, 0)], mode='constant')` depending on which axis you want to pad.